# How to find out which application runs behind port 31337?

Tags: ports, network-scanners, backdoor

I found an open port on a "Kartina Quattro" (https://www.kartina.tv/article/247-kartina-quattro). It's a device for watching russian TV channels.

The port number is **31337** and the  Service is called **Elite**.

After some research I found out that this port and servicename are often used by hackers.

I asked the support of the vendor and they only said that the ports 27000-32000 are used for the streaming of the channels. But at the time I scanned the ports, the device was in stand-by mode.

How can I figure out if it was really hacked or it's a legit service running on it?

Comment: How did you discover the port? How many scans have you run? Can you capture packets from the device?

Comment: What access do you have to the device to run diagnostics?

Comment: Note: `31337` looks like the letters `ELEET`, which sounds like "elite". Several variations of `LEET-speak` exist.

Comment: I used "Fing" (Network Scan App) and also nmap. I have physical access but I dont know If its possible to get a shell on that thing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can get *on* the device to see what is running on that port, you will have to capture packets from the device and make a lot of guesses about how it runs.